# Ui Not recomposing when deleting items from room database in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-jetpack-compose

I'm using room database with jetpack compose,upon deleting all items the ui is not recomposing unless i move to another screen and come back again , any help would be appreciated , Thank you

- This is my code

```
fun CheckOutScreen(shopViewModel: ShopViewModel, 
                   navHostController: NavHostController,
                   list : SnapshotStateList<PurchaseModel> ) {


    val firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    val databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val totalAmount = remember { mutableStateOf(0.0) }
    val count = remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    val isDialogShowing = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val isProgressShowing = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val isDataSaving = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val isMovingToAnotherScreen = remember { mutableStateOf(false)}

    list.forEach {
        if(count.value < list.size){
            totalAmount.value += it.totalPrice
            count.value++
        }
    }

    Scaffold{
        Column {
            Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                Text(text = "Cart", modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(1f)
                    .padding(10.dp), color = Color.DarkGray,
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.h1, fontSize = 17.sp)
                IconButton(onClick = {
                    isDialogShowing.value = true
                }) {
                    Icon(Icons.Filled.Delete,"")
                }
            }
            if(list.size == 0){
                Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.Center, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                    Text("No Items In The Cart", style = MaterialTheme.typography.h1,
                        color = Color.DarkGray , fontSize = 17.sp)
                }
            }
            else {
                Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.Center){
                    Column() {
                        Text(text = "Purchase To : " + list[0].fullName, modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 10.dp,
                            end = 10.dp, top = 5.dp), fontSize = 17.sp,style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1)
                        LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier
                            .weight(1f)
                            .padding(top = 10.dp)){
                            items(list.size, key = { item -> item.hashCode()}){ pos ->
                                val dismissState = rememberDismissState(confirmStateChange = {
                                    if(it == DismissValue.DismissedToStart || it == DismissValue.DismissedToEnd){
                                        shopViewModel.deletePurchase(list[pos].purchaseId!!)
                                        Toast.makeText(context,"Item Successfully Dismissed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                                    }
                                    true
                                })

                                if(!isMovingToAnotherScreen.value){
                                    SwipeToDismiss(
                                        state = dismissState,
                                        background = {},
                                        dismissContent = {
                                            Card(elevation = 10.dp, modifier = Modifier
                                                .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(6.dp))
                                                .padding(5.dp)) {
                                                Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                                                    Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
                                                        AsyncImage(model = ImageRequest.Builder(context).data(list[pos].productImage).build(),
                                                            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                                                            modifier = Modifier
                                                                .width(80.dp)
                                                                .height(80.dp)
                                                                .padding(10.dp),
                                                            contentDescription = "")
                                                    }
                                                    Column(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)) {
                                                        Text(list[pos].title, modifier = Modifier.padding(5.dp), fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
                                                        Text("Quantity : " + list[pos].totalQuantity)
                                                        Text("Due To : " + list[pos].totalPrice)
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },
                                        directions = setOf(DismissDirection.StartToEnd,DismissDirection.EndToStart))
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        Card(modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 20.dp, topEnd = 20.dp))) {
                            Button(modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 20.dp, end = 20.dp),onClick = {
                                isProgressShowing.value = true
                            }) {
                                Text("Pay ${totalAmount.value}")
                            }
                        }


                    }
                }
                AnimatedVisibility(visible  = isProgressShowing.value) {
                    CircularProgressIndicator(color = Color.DarkGray)
                }
            }

        }

        if(isProgressShowing.value){

            val map = hashMapOf<String,Any>()
            map["list"] = list
            map["uid"] = firebaseAuth.currentUser!!.uid
            map["totalPrice"] = totalAmount.value.toString()

            val db = databaseReference.child("Purchases")
            db.child(firebaseAuth.currentUser!!.uid)
                .child(Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis.toString())
                .setValue(map)
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    isDataSaving.value = true
                }
                .addOnFailureListener {

                }
        }
        if(isDialogShowing.value){
            AlertDialog(
                onDismissRequest = { isDialogShowing.value = false },
                confirmButton = {
                    TextButton(onClick = {
                        shopViewModel.deletePurchases()
                        isDialogShowing.value = false
                        Toast.makeText(context,"All items are successfully removed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }) {
                        Text("Proceed")
                    }
                },
                dismissButton = {
                    TextButton(onClick = { isDialogShowing.value = false }) {
                        Text("Cancel")
                    }
                },
                title = { Text("Removing Items ") },
                text = { Text("Do you want to remove items from cart ! ") }
            )
        }
        if(isDataSaving.value){
            LaunchedEffect(Unit){
                delay(3000)
                isMovingToAnotherScreen.value = true
                shopViewModel.deletePurchases()
                isProgressShowing.value  = false
                isDataSaving.value = false
                navHostController.navigate(AppRouting.Payment.route)
            }
        }
    }
    BackHandler {
        isMovingToAnotherScreen.value = true
        navHostController.popBackStack()
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you share call site of this function ? Maybe I can help, If I see which list item you passing as a parameter to this function.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely because of not updating value of your `State`. In you example it's always the same list. You either need to set value with new instance of list or use `SnapshotStateList`. You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73119450/5457853) also.

Comment: Isn't there any chance you can replace `state : State<MutableList<PurchaseModel>>` with `SnapshotStateList<PurchaseModel>`?

Comment: To trigger recomposition you should change state.value which is List or you need to you SnapshatStateList and remove items from it.

Comment: I don't get why all of the items are not deleted. You are able to delete items one by one right? But not the last item? Your items are deleted on firebase but not on your local list right?

Comment: My bad mate i thought it was recomposing onSwipeToDelete but it is not , sorry that was my mistake , they both do not work , i'm using SnapShotStateList as you recommended but don't know Ui is not recomposing ..